# How to read images in .NET?

Tags: .net, image, image-processing

What API or component could I use to read images (e.g. scanned copies) using C# and .Net?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Aforge.Net](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/).

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx) is a sample on how to use it

Answer (score 1):

[System.Drawing.Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) is the easy way to get started.

It can read BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF

Answer (score 1):

use openCV. you can find it [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

you can use this library perfectly with c++. if you need to use it in C# use this [wrapper](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

you can also use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on the technology you want to use; in the case of WPF you'd use built-in classes in System.Windows.Media.Imaging, which handle the most common formats natively (bmp, jpeg, png, gif, tiff, wmp).